# Relative Angle Vectors

Tags: c++, arrays, matlab, vector

I am pretty new to MATLAB and programming in general, so apologies in advance if this is too trivial of a question.

Here is my dilemma, I have a system where two vectors are running away from each other out of the origin, one with a magnitude of 200 and another with a magnitude of 150, these figures are given.

After the user inputs their magnitudes and angles in a cartesian coordinate system, the angles are converted to radians and the following calculations are performed:

```
compA = MagA*[cos(AngleA), sin(AngleA)];
compB = MagB*[cos(AngleB), sin(AngleB)];
AngleAwrtB = compA-compB;
```

Where compA and compB are the x any y components of of the two vectors "end points" and AwrtB is "A with respect to B" . MagA and MagB are the magnitudes of each vector.

So I now have the angle of vector A with respect to B, now I need to find the magnitude of vector A with respect to vector B, any ideas on how I could do this? I want to use something like the following:

```
MagAwrtB = MagA-MagB
```

I am just worried that this is mathematically incorrect, that there is some other trigonometric relation that I am missing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is a relative magnitude? Are you talking about the ratio of magnitudes? Or maybe what you want is a dot product of A with B/|B|. Please clarify.

Comment: is this in Matlab language or C++?

Comment: Hi Lakshay, I hope that I am posting this in the correct spot. More specifically, relative speed. I am asked to generate a script that can find the relative angle that another vector is moving at from the original vector, as well as the relative speed. The units in this case are in mi/hr (not that it matters). Sorry for not communicating that more clearly.

Comment: `compA-compB` is not an angle, it's a vector.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is pretty much the definition of the dot product, which can be achieved in Matlab with the `dot` function (or manually with the formula, in 2D it's straightforward).

Best